# C: Permission Denied with open() (GCC for windows)

Tags: c, gcc

So, I just write:

```
int fdes = open(path, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC);
```

And if the file that the `path` referred to doesn't exist, this code works. But if it does, the code returns with `errno` 13 : Permission Denied. I never use the `O_EXCL` mode at all.

I have searched for the solution to this problem a long time and I am really confused.  Can you explain the problem?

I use the **GCC for windows(4.5.2)**. Your answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If you use `O_CREAT`, you should supply a mode as the third argument to `open()`.
2. If the file does exist, you must have write permission on the file.  The error indicates (strongly suggests) that the file is created without write permission.  This might be a consequence of not creating it with a sensible mode.

Note that (on Unix at least) you can create a file for writing with mode `0444` (or even `0`); the permissions affect everyone else, but not the process that created the file while it uses the file descriptor that created the file.

Comment: "Permission denied" can also occur if you don't have permission to read any of the parent directories of the path you're trying to create.

Comment: Or, I suppose, if you don't have write permission in the directory so you cannot create a file in it.  Yes, you're right; the directory permissions could also be a factor.

Comment: But the problem is that I can create files but i can't open any file that already **exists**. My OS is MS Windows, so i think i needn't to write with the `mode`. (The first time i run this code, the file created, but when i run it again, it returns `errno` 13. After i delete the file the code created, the code works again.)

Comment: You're outside my area of expertise.  Look at the permissions on the file created, and the directory containing the files.  Look at the ACLs.  Something in there is going to explain it.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I checked the permission of the file that the code created. And found the file have the **READONLY** flag. It's my fault that didn't check the permission of the file (I never have a strong permission sense in Windows XD). So now, i call the `open()` with the `mode`, then it works! Thanks for your suggestion.